# if one checkbox is checked, how to uncheck another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems with my calculator, I have five checkboxes (costOne, costTwo, costThree, costFour, costFive)

When I check **costOne**, then **costTwo** should turn off, but if I click on this **costTwo** (which then is turned off) then **costOne** should be turned off.

My code works only partly: when I click on the **costOne**, then you cannot click on the **costTwo** anymore (because it becomes disabled), but when I click on **costOne** it turns off and **costTwo** turns on at the same time - this is exactly what I want.

But I can't click **costTwo**.

The first and the third input I need to have this linked behaviour.

Here is the relevant code:

```
//calculator
var init = $('.switch input').on('click', function() {
    var value1 = 0;
    var value2 = 0;

    var costOne = $("#cost-one"),
        costTwo = $("#cost-three");


    if (costOne.is(':checked')) { 
        costOne.prop("checked", true);
        costTwo.prop("checked", false);
    } else { 
        costOne.prop("checked", false);
        costTwo.prop("checked", true);
    }

    init.filter(':checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
        value1 += (+$(this).find('span.cost-one').text());
        value2 += (+$(this).find('span.cost-two').text());
    });

    $('.counter-one span').eq(0).html(value1 + '&nbsp;');
    $('.counter-two span').eq(0).html(value2 + '&nbsp;');
});
```

Comment: Why not use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes? - From what I read of your question it'd give you the desired effect - unless I am misunderstand part of your spec.

Comment: Should it be possible that both options are not checked?

Comment: Disabled means `disabled`; it can not receive user input ...may be the title is misleading!

Comment: I updated your question removing the ambiguity with "disabled", which sometimes seems to denote "unchecked". Please have a look if this correctly reflects your question.

Comment: I updated my answer to enable "unchecking" for radios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code (simplified to focus on the issue):

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    if (id == 'cost-one' || id == 'cost-three') {
        // Make sure the two have opposite values:
        var other = id == 'cost-one' ? 'cost-three' : 'cost-one';
        $('#'+other).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
One: <input type="checkbox" id="cost-one"><br>
Two: <input type="checkbox" id="cost-two"><br>
Three: <input type="checkbox" id="cost-three" checked><br>
```

The *other* variable will identify the *id* of the other checkbox: if you clicked on **cost-one**, it will refer to **cost-three**, and vice versa.

Then that other checkbox will get the opposite checked state.

To be consistent, you should also check one of the two on page load, so I have added the `checked` attribute for the third checkbox.

As has been expressed in comments, this behaviour is standard with radio buttons. So, unless your library does not support the same widget-look for it, you could maybe better use those instead (for those linked items).

Answer (score 0):

just try with this jquery

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('.example').on('change', function() {
      $('.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   });
});
</script>
```

```html
<input class="example" type="checkbox" name="ny">
<input class="example" type="checkbox" name="bos">
<input class="example" type="checkbox" name="sfo">
<input class="example" type="checkbox" name="dc">
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons already do that natively, as the comment suggests:

```html
<input type=radio name="a">
<input type=radio name="a">
```

Just use the same `name` attribute.

If you want to allow unchecking, use this:

```js
var checked;
$('[name="a"]').on('click', function () {
  if(checked === this) {
    checked = this.checked = false;
  } else {
    checked = this;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=radio name="a">
<input type=radio name="a">
```